# How to display the ANSI Escape codes in javascript?

Tags: javascript, ansi-escape

**my code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<script>
document.write('\u001b[41m Hello World \u001b[40m');
console.log('\u001b[41m Hello World');
</script> 

</body>
</html>
```

**output**
[output pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LqatA.png)

In console the text comes with red background color. But ,  in web page it comes like this `\u001b[41m Hello World \u001b[40m`

I want to display all terminal escape codes using javascript. How can I do this with javascript ?

Comment: incase of output in a document you could use CSS styling instead

Comment: Could you explain in detail?

Comment: HTML doesn't implement ANSI escape codes. To get coloured text, you need to wrap it in HTML tags and apply proper CSS styling. You look as the example at https://www.npmjs.com/package/ansi-to-html

Answer (score 1):

Try this way,
Use this library - https://www.npmjs.com/package/ansi-up

CODE:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/ansi_up@4.0.4/ansi_up.js"></script>

    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    
    <div id="ansi-output"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
 
        // Get a reference to the HTML element
        const ansiOutput = document.getElementById('ansi-output');

        // Initialize the ANSI-UP library
        const ansi_up = new AnsiUp();

        var ansiText = '\u001b[41m Hello World \u001b[40m'

        

        // Convert ANSI to HTML and display it
        ansiOutput.innerHTML = ansi_up.ansi_to_html(ansiText);

     
        </script>
</body>
</html>
```